# Куда http-сервер сохраняет информацию об ошибках?

Tags: apache, nginx, nginx-faq

Сайт не сохраняет текст с тегами.
То есть вообще не сохраняется ничего. Ни текст ни теги.

Подскажите пожалуйста с чем это может быть связано?
В какой-то лог это записывается - что произошла ошибка - чтобы посмотреть из-за чего это происходит?

в mysql стоит кодировка UTF-8
есть доступ к SSH

Спасибо)

Comment: Хорошо, а как мне ее посмотреть? Какая у меня ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В какой-то лог это записывается - что произошла ошибка - чтобы посмотреть из-за чего это происходит?

количество сохраняемых подробностей, расположение, да и вообще существование файла, в который записываются ошибки, зависит от настройки *http-сервера* для данного сайта.

например, при использовании дистрибутивной сборки *apache* с дефолтными настройками:

- в *debian gnu/linux* и основанных на нём дистрибутивах (*ubuntu*, *mint* и т.д. и т.п.) это будет файл `/var/log/apache2/error.log`
- в *redhat* и основанных на нём дистрибутивах (*centos*, *fedora* и т.д. и т.п.) это будет файл `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

для дистрибутивной сборки *nginx* с дефолтными настройками:

- в *debian gnu/linux* и «наследниках»: `/var/log/nginx/error.log`
- в *redhat* и «наследниках»: `/var/log/nginx/error.log`